# How do I convert uint to int in C#?

Tags: c#

How do I convert uint to int in C#?

Comment: Be aware that you can overflow the value of an int if you do this.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to be sure to gracefully handle the exception by putting your object in an acceptable state if the value of the uint is greater than Int32.MaxValue (which happens to be 2,147,483,647)

Comment: It would be safer to convert the `uint` to a `long` as a `long` can contain all `uint` values where as an `int` can't ([as already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131843/how-do-i-convert-uint-to-int-in-c#comment949122_1131843))

Answer (score 231, accepted):

Given:

```
 uint n = 3;

int i = checked((int)n); //throws OverflowException if n > Int32.MaxValue
int i = unchecked((int)n); //converts the bits only 
                           //i will be negative if n > Int32.MaxValue

int i = (int)n; //same behavior as unchecked
```

or

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32(n); //same behavior as checked
```

--EDIT

Included info as mentioned by [Kenan E. K.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133143/kenan-e-k)

Comment: Note that if the `uint` is greater than `int.MaxValue` you'll get a negative result if you use a cast, or an exception if you use `Convert.ToInt32`.

Comment: Which makes Convert.ToInt32 the better choice imo.

Comment: @Luke - No, not necessarily. When casting it depends on your project build settings as to whether checked or unchecked arithmentic is the default. In addition, you can modify this on a local basis using the checked and unchecked keywords.

Comment: @Greg: That's true, but the default out-of-the-box setting is unchecked.

Comment: @GregBeech Is this behaviour portable ? in case of unchecked approach ??

Comment: @mmcdole a negative result could be the intended result. Both int and uint hold the same number of values, so this will give you a unique mapping for each and every value between the two data-types. If you have a random number generator that produces every value of a uint, being able to convert it to any value of an int is quite handy.

Answer (score 14):

Assuming you want to simply lift the 32bits from one type and dump them as-is into the other type:

```
uint asUint = unchecked((uint)myInt);
int asInt = unchecked((int)myUint);
```

The destination type will blindly pick the 32 bits and reinterpret them.

Conversely if you're more interested in keeping the decimal/numerical values within the range of the destination type itself:

```
uint asUint = checked((uint)myInt);
int asInt = checked((int)myUint);
```

In this case, you'll get overflow exceptions if:

- casting a negative int (eg: -1) to an uint
- casting a positive uint between 2,147,483,648 and 4,294,967,295 to an int

In our case, we wanted the `unchecked` solution to preserve the 32bits as-is, so here are some examples:

## Examples

### int => uint

```
int....: 0000000000 (00-00-00-00)
asUint.: 0000000000 (00-00-00-00)
------------------------------
int....: 0000000001 (01-00-00-00)
asUint.: 0000000001 (01-00-00-00)
------------------------------
int....: -0000000001 (FF-FF-FF-FF)
asUint.: 4294967295 (FF-FF-FF-FF)
------------------------------
int....: 2147483647 (FF-FF-FF-7F)
asUint.: 2147483647 (FF-FF-FF-7F)
------------------------------
int....: -2147483648 (00-00-00-80)
asUint.: 2147483648 (00-00-00-80)
```

### uint => int

```
uint...: 0000000000 (00-00-00-00)
asInt..: 0000000000 (00-00-00-00)
------------------------------
uint...: 0000000001 (01-00-00-00)
asInt..: 0000000001 (01-00-00-00)
------------------------------
uint...: 2147483647 (FF-FF-FF-7F)
asInt..: 2147483647 (FF-FF-FF-7F)
------------------------------
uint...: 4294967295 (FF-FF-FF-FF)
asInt..: -0000000001 (FF-FF-FF-FF)
------------------------------
```

## Code

```
int[] testInts = { 0, 1, -1, int.MaxValue, int.MinValue };
uint[] testUints = { uint.MinValue, 1, uint.MaxValue / 2, uint.MaxValue };

foreach (var Int in testInts)
{
    uint asUint = unchecked((uint)Int);
    Console.WriteLine("int....: {0:D10} ({1})", Int, BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(Int)));
    Console.WriteLine("asUint.: {0:D10} ({1})", asUint, BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(asUint)));
    Console.WriteLine(new string('-',30));
}
Console.WriteLine(new string('=', 30));
foreach (var Uint in testUints)
{
    int asInt = unchecked((int)Uint);
    Console.WriteLine("uint...: {0:D10} ({1})", Uint, BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(Uint)));
    Console.WriteLine("asInt..: {0:D10} ({1})", asInt, BitConverter.ToString(BitConverter.GetBytes(asInt)));
    Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 30));
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Take note of the [`checked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw(v=vs.140).aspx) and [`unchecked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a569z7k8(v=vs.140).aspx) keywords.

It matters if you want the result truncated to the int or an exception raised if the result doesnt fit in signed 32 bits. The default is unchecked.

Comment: I believe the default is unchecked.  +1 for pointing this out--the source of hard to debug errors.

Comment: You are right, my bad, thanks! -"The default value for this option is /checked-"

Comment: Unchecked doesn't "truncate".

Answer (score 9):

`Convert.ToInt32()` takes `uint` as a value.

Answer (score 1):

```
uint i = 10;
int j = (int)i;
```

or

```
int k = Convert.ToInt32(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the value contained in the uint can be represented in an int, then it is as simple as:

`int val = (int) uval;`

Answer (score 0):

I would say using tryParse, it'll return 'false' if the uint is to big for an int.
Don't forget that a uint can go much bigger than a int, as long as you going > 0

Answer (score -1):

```
int intNumber = (int)uintNumber;
```

Depending on what kind of values you are expecting, you may want to check how big uintNumber is before doing the conversion. An int has a max value of about .5 of a uint.