# CRC32 return int32

Tags: c#, .net, crc32

I look for code that calculate crc32 and return int32, but I found just func that return uint or hexa or string. When I tried to convert the crc32 to int - it was too big to be int.
Do you know how to calculate crc32 that return **int32**??

Or can you change the code in this link so - the code will return int32 instead of hexa?? http://damieng.com/blog/2006/08/08/calculating_crc32_in_c_and_net

Thanks,
Chani

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131843/how-do-i-convert-uint-to-int-in-c

Comment: If I convert from uint to int it returns negative sometimes, so - Is it checksum??? maybe 2 string will return the same crc32 because of the convert.

Comment: @Chanipoz CRC32 obviously has collisions, but casting to a signed int does not introduce new collisions. If you want no collisions at all, you should use a cryptographic hash with a length of at least 128 bits, but that of course doesn't fit into a `Int32`.

Answer (score 5):

use `unchecked((Int32)someUInt32)`. That can return negative numbers, but that's to be expected, it's CRC32 and not CRC31 after all.

No idea why you're mentioning hex, the code you linked doesn't use hexadecimal numbers anywhere. It just uses `UInt32` and `byte[]`.

Comment: In the link - the code return string that contains hexa like: 'cc54a3'. The UInt32 and byte[] use just in the inner func.