# C# signed/unsigned cast issues

Tags: c#

I need to convert between signed integers and their internal representation as series of bytes. In C I was using functions like:

```
unsigned char hibyte(unsigned short i)
{return i>>8;}

unsigned char lobyte(unsigned short i)
{return i & 0xFF;}

unsigned short makeshort(unsigned char hb, unsigned char lb)
{return ((short)hb << 8) | (short)lb;}
```

The problem is that this code does not work under C# because the rules of signed/unsigned cast are not the same: as I understand a C# cast mean conversion of the value whereas in C casting between signed/unsigned types  does not modify the underlying data. Moreover in C#,  for signed numbers the >> operator shifts in the sign bit. All this makes it difficult to convert my code to C# e.g.

1) the C# function

```
public static byte hibyte(short i)
{return (byte) (i>>8);}
```

throws an overflow exception if i is negative

2) the C# function

```
public static ushort makeshort(byte hb, byte lb)
{return (short) (((ushort)hb << 8) | (ushort)lb); }
```

throws an overflow exception if the resulting short is negative. Here
the expression  "(ushort)hb << 8" works because the shift is done on unsigned number.  But then I need to interpret the same data as a signed integer and I don't know how to do it. I understand for C# such C-like cast is cheating because a positive value may become a negative value but this is what I actually need (eg. for processing a byte stream read from a device etc.)  For the moment I'm using the C code compiled as an unmanaged dll for all binary manipulations like this but this is not very elegant and I'm sure this can be done somehow (possibly simply) in C#.  Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Might just be a simple case of wrapping that code in `unchecked { ... }`, which suppresses the overflow checks.

Comment: Have you looked into the [`BitConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) class?

Comment: Such casts are not "cheating", it's perfectly valid (though `checked` contexts like to complain about lots of innocuous things) to reinterpret the bits as you do.

Comment: loot at [How do I convert uint to int in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1131851/1155650)

Comment: is `ushort` in `public static ushort makeshort` a typo?

Comment: The reason this is cheating is because you're relying on the internal implementation of those data types - that's a big no-no in multi-platform programming. In fact, it was a bad idea in C as well, since C was designed basically as portable assembly - it was designed to run on such a wide variety of hardware that tricks like this had no chance of working. Sure, there's little variety *now* - you're not likely to find hardware with two's complement signed numbers, for example; but you still have to treat e.g. endianness properly. Stick to safe casts, and you can do the same without issue.

Comment: @Luaan it was worse in C. In C#, the internal representation (if it can even be called that) is part of the specification.

Comment: "



 



 

is ushort in public static ushort makeshort a typo? " yes, should have been short

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several answers have already noted the `BitConverter` class, as well as using `unchecked` with bit shifts and casts. I'll just quickly demonstrate the third option: "C-style union structs".

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct Converter
{
   [FieldOffset(0)]
   public ushort UshortValue;
   [FieldOffset(0)]
   public short ShortValue;
   [FieldOffset(0)]
   public byte LoByte;    
   [FieldOffset(1)]
   public byte HiByte;
}
```

Then use like so.

```
ushort test1 = new Converter { ShortValue = -123 }.UshortValue; // 65413
ushort test2 = new Converter { HiByte = 1, LoByte = 100 }.UshortValue; // 356
byte test3 = new Converter { UshortValue = 356 }.LoByte;  // 100
```

It has the advantage over `BitConverter` that you don't need to allocate a temporary byte array.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `BitConverter` class to do this instead:

```
short x = 1;
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(x);
short y = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
```

This has overloads for the other integral types `int` and `long` too.

If you really want to write the code yourself, you can avoid overflow exceptions by specifying `unchecked` like so:

```
public static byte hibyte(short i)
{
    unchecked
    {
        return (byte)(i >> 8);
    }
}

public static ushort makeushort(byte hb, byte lb)
{
    unchecked
    {
        return (ushort)((hb << 8) | lb);
    }
}

public static short makeshort(byte hb, byte lb)
{
    unchecked
    {
        return (short)((hb << 8) | lb);
    }
}
```

I'd just use `BitConverter` though; it's pretty fast. However, note that it always uses the endianness of the machine on which the code is running.

This is reported via [`BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.islittleendian%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

If the data you're converting has a different endianness you have to do it yourself.

Comment: BitConverter may even be faster thanks to [its internal use of unsafe code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/bitconverter.cs,1618fc20415532f2).

Comment: @ScottChamberlain This is especially the case when the values are properly aligned - in that case, it's nothing more than a simple "reinterpret cast" with a copy. However, it must be noted that it will always use the endianness of the machine, which isn't very useful for interchange data formats.

Comment: @Luaan That's a good point (endianness), so I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: many thanks, both unchecked and BitConvert do what I want, this is what I was looking for.   Paul

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you can use the `BitConverter` class, though they failed to account for endianness in the actual code (it was just briefly mentioned at the end):

```
public static (byte Hibyte, byte Lobyte) GetBytes(short i)
{   // This is my recommendation; it gets both bytes in one call, so it
    // may be more efficient.
    var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        Array.Reverse(bytes)
    return (bytes[0], bytes[1]);
}

public static (byte Hibyte, byte Lobyte) GetBytes(ushort i)
{   // BitConverter works equally well with unsigned types.
    var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        Array.Reverse(bytes)
    return (bytes[0], bytes[1]);
}

public static byte Hibyte(short i)
{   // If you want to use your original schema, here's the hi byte:
    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        return BitConverter.GetBytes()[1];
    return BitConverter.GetBytes()[0];
}

public static byte Hibyte(ushort i)
{   // Again, same thing works for ushort
    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        return BitConverter.GetBytes()[1];
    return BitConverter.GetBytes()[0];
}

public static short MakeShort(byte hb, byte lb)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[] { hb, lb };
    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        Array.Reverse(bytes);
    return BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes);
}

public static ushort MakeUShort(byte hb, byte lb)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[] { hb, lb };
    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        Array.Reverse(bytes);
    return BitConverter.ToUInt16(bytes);
}
```

And, while others have mentioned using `unchecked`, they neglect one issue: as you noted in the original question, when doing a right shift on signed integral types, the sign bit gets repeated, so while this works:

```
public static byte Hibyte(ushort i)
{ return (byte)(i >> 8); }
// No need for unchecked, because result will always fit in one byte and is never < 0.

public static byte Lobyte(ushort i)
{ return (byte)(i & 0xFF); } // No need for unchecked for the same reason.

public static byte LoByte(short i)
{ return (byte)(i & 0xFF); } 
// Like above, no need for unchecked for the same reasons; also, bitwise & works the same 
// for both signed and unsigned types.

public static ushort MakeUShort(byte hb, byte lb)
{ return (ushort)((hb << 8) | lb); } 
// Again, no need for unchecked; result is always 16 bits and never negative.

public static short MakeShort(byte hb, byte lb)
{ unchecked { return (short)((hb << 8) | lb); } }
// This time, we may need unchecked because result may overflow short.
```

...the code given for the high byte of a *signed* `short` needs an extra cast:

```
public static byte Hibyte(short i)
{ unchecked { return (byte)((ushort)i >> 8); } }
// Again, the unchecked is needed, this time because i may be negative, 
// which may need to be accounted for when casting to a ushort.
```

By casting the signed `short` to an unsigned `ushort` before shifting, we keep the sign bit from being added to the front 8 times. Alternatively, we could use a bitwise `&` to ignore the propagated sign bits:

```
public static byte HiByte (short i)
{ return (byte)((i >> 8) & 0xFF); }
// Since bitwise operations never result in overflow, and by the time we cast at the end, 
// the number is guaranteed to fit in a byte and be >= 0, we no longer need any unchecked blocks.
```

Any of these would generate the same results.