# How does type casting work from double to byte

Tags: c#, .net

I have a code where type casting returns a value much different from the larger value.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double a = 345.09;
    byte c = (byte) a;
    Console.WriteLine(c);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This returns the value `89`. What is the reason behind it?

Comment: Note: 345-256=89

Comment: @Ansul a byte can only contain 256 values. after that, it starts counting at 0 again. the rest basically "overflows"

Comment: See [Integral numeric types](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types) | [Safely Performing a Narrowing Numeric Cast](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/c-cookbook/0596003390/ch01s13.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert uint to int in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131843/how-do-i-convert-uint-to-int-in-c)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

what happens is that only the last 8 bits are taken when you cast the number. Let me explain with an example using ints. I use int for simplicity, because if you cast `double` to a non-float number representation than the decimal places are discarded anyway.

First we look at the binary representation of the number 345:

```
string binaryInt = Convert.ToString(345, 2);
Console.WriteLine(binaryInt);
```

The output is :

> `1 0101 1001`

When we now take only the last 8 bits, which is the size of a `byte` type:

```
string eightLastBits = binaryInt.Substring(binaryInt.Length-8);
Console.WriteLine(eightLastBits);
```

We get:

> `0101 1001`

If we convert this to `byte` again you will see that the result is 89:

```
byte backAgain = Convert.ToByte(eightLastBits, 2);
Console.WriteLine(backAgain);
```

Output:

> `89`

EDIT:

As pointed out by [InBetween](https://stackoverflow.com/users/767890/inbetween) the int example is the real deal and what really happens during casting.

Looking at the [implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/double.cs) of the conversion of double to byte:

```
/// <internalonly/>
byte IConvertible.ToByte(IFormatProvider provider) {
    return Convert.ToByte(m_value);
}
```

If we look at the [Convert.ToByte](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,b4a4ac090ddb2b58) method implementation: we see that the double if first converted to an integer:

```
public static byte ToByte(double value) {
    return ToByte(ToInt32(value));
}
```

Comment: I guess this is the reason behind range of byte type. `255` in binary = `11111111`(max limit of 8 bits) Cool I learned a new thing today. Every day is a school day..

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar: Exactly. An unsigned byte ( `byte` in C#) can store a number from `0` to `255`, a signed byte (`SByte` in .net) a number from `-128` to `127`, using [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Comment: A perfect Explanation. Got to learn new thing. All other answers do explain, but since this is in-depth, will give a mark of the accepted answer (it does not mean the other answer is wrong).

Comment: +1. Using `int` is actually not an example, it's what really happens: `(byte)a` calls `a.ToInt32()` before casting to `byte` so the code essentially is `(byte)(int)a`

Comment: @InBetween can you give me a link to this info. I will adjust my answer and incorporate this into it. Thanx. Or you can simply edit it and I confirm the edit.

Comment: Check out the reference source of convert.cs; https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,b4a4ac090ddb2b58,references. In particular `ToByte(double d)`

Comment: @InBetween ok, I made an edit. could you have a look

Answer (score 4):

[Range of byte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.byte?view=net-5.0#remarks) starts from 0 to 255, you are getting result as 89 because it starts counting again from 0 once it goes beyond 255. i.e

```
byte c = (byte) a;  //345 - 255  (consider `0` as well)
Console.WriteLine(c); // i.e. 89
```

The reason behind the range of byte:

> `byte` stores 8-bit data. `0000 0000` and `1111 1111` (8-bit binary data) values can be
> defined as  `Min` and `Max` value to `byte` variable respectively, so
> in integer it turns into `0` and `255`

Answer (score 2):

Note that this is one of the few cases where the result isn't specified.

From the [language spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#explicit-conversions), omitting the irrelevant cases

> For a conversion from `float` or `double` to an integral type, the processing depends on the overflow checking context (The checked and unchecked operators) in which the conversion takes place:
>
> In an unchecked context, the conversion always succeeds, and proceeds as follows.
>
> If the value of the operand is NaN or infinite, [...]
>
> Otherwise, the source operand is rounded towards zero to the nearest integral value. If this integral value is within the range of the destination type, [...]
>
> Otherwise, **the result of the conversion is an unspecified value of the destination type**

Presumably, the implementation simply stripped off the higher bits after converting to the nearest integral value, leaving just the least significant 8 bits, since that's likely the most convenient thing to do at that point. But do note that according to this spec, `0` is just as a valid value as `89` is, for this conversion.